# how to connect to azure mongo db locally?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,date
import os
# conn = pymongo.MongoClient('://:27017', username='username', password='pass', authSource='admin')
# db = conn.test_database

client = MongoClient(os.getenv("104.211.182.12"))
db = client.test_database   #Select the database
db.authenticate(name=os.getenv("username"),password=os.getenv("password"))
```

I have tried this out with actual password but doesnt working

Comment: What does `os.getenv("104.211.182.12")` do? I suppose you should pass `104.211.182.12` as an address, as the `host` parameter. See [the docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html).

Comment: client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://adminuser:adpass123@194.211.482.12:8000/test_database") # defaults to port 27017

db = client.test_database

# print the number of documents in a collection
print db.questions.count()
x = db.questions.find({})
for i in x:
 print i['wasAnswered']

Comment: i tried this one also.but throwing a timed out error